# How do I get the font and canvas details from a canvas fingerprint?

Tags: html5-canvas, base64, data-uri, fingerprinting

I'm using ClientJS for browser fingerprinting.

I don't know how to identify what Cancvas fill, Canvas stroke, Canvas font name, Canvas font size, etc. is using a client.

Sorry for my poor English.

I'm getting the results like this when I Copy-paste in the address bar:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [atob](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#atob) to decode the base64 string:

```js
console.log(atob("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAYhUlEQVR4Xu2cB3RU1dqG330mvQEBEkkooQSQIiWFXhXpICqIF5FmZgIW1AtX4CpGbFiuIookk9CUIjakW2hKNyF0AgkkIEiAkAapk5nZ/zoTggGCXi78mn3vO2u5Vlhzzp53nu87z9pnnz0K8EUCJEACihAQiuRkzDtIQBoh7+BwygwlzGC/K1OtioOygIoX8D+JT2H9J9R4TmUgQGFVhir8yRkorD8ZOD/ujhGoXMIaO88bQjpj3hNZd+wbcqAbCFBYbApVCdworLHzAuBkfQHAKABVIHEWAm/C4hKHhWOK8ESsPzT7FkjxLKTYd/XvWON3twXBGOMByM8gtTmoaKwIc2/A/gyKPIbh08fzoR8v5SRAmCAQACAXwCJYnd7C/HFnbyvLf/nJf5awLkk3PCIi8KzchN7i8E2p5kgPTMJD+ER0gDNsmIJvHf/pf9/JF9ew7iTNv2asa4U1bm4bGMSXkJgNIWJhNhbCFHM37DADSIAQk2HXfO+YpMp/55GfeMKt4HNAmz1mvDERVrgtCMfpq4eUF9bp1GIE3/UWAG9YXf6JBWMzMGK2DzxcpgDoASEGwmy6+Ncgrfyf+mcI6wK88QRGYjVa4Vs5+6bCskoNz2MoJATeEl9Dl5d+3gAcwATx4x2FSWHdUZx/yWC/CWv0Aje4FC+BxE+INc0eGy8aOwvHLKtpUZFn9fPn67fy8syKPpDUx5yc1G5t44Y/z+zU9dNB27f9rR3shn92v3fe/Zcu1dz42bJXu0CIEQBKAJhhcXkFC8fkOGZmwv41IFcBYjyA2hDyB0CMRaH7JYeshOjn4lKAPn0+2l7L/8SsmDB8eb2wRj3296WawXb/ss9fa19U6PPMuDHGeIMzxkugtd3qXCX9XHA7d/fLa6pUPz1jfhiOXUM1cq4fbOKtq/mk/ABCvAazqaB05mhbCIhEAJMh5TLk+EbAJ7MxDNoiSLSCkFsgkQKg7tWZ3h+VLXJuIGziWQixDmbTZoyZUwfOTu8AeNDBqHyGCHNHwP4+IEJKh5V7AO05xBp3/C4/s/EcjGZd4IDZ+AIgSp8CRkTrM+VgpJyLRHBAeNnYBtgNITiF9/EFOooTKIEBsbIzpmMQcuCB8u8dlgH4GN0wEZsQjAsQV4b+va+9XrZwSOd+HMFmNMEHbotwOfwYmp0B2qZde2YK/DAURizCQtTzOIMN9wCHfLyRLP3wcMYpDDhohcsdmmhRWH/UrJX//d+EFWFuDsjF0OQw45jI2jBAv9WKt1mwYN73yDH1RTupIcJi8by0ePGbfRoE7X+zTFjJyR3HoaBoJzxcP4XATlhcZkGzO8NQ8i8AzhDCeHVmBnkSVudxsGsFcC7+FMBhxEZOwZUZVk3/1AVDBr99nwA23ExYzi5FPZZ+9kZdi9Xj0rChURe8vTLzhQFzotvg5BO74K8ZMB4SQRYbohZ2wElHGUrHXwKI0xDQL2T9lnIBgGSknHsBjQKrO2aOwGYAk+Bk1WB1coOUqwF8hhzfj1AtuyskFgNy3+8LSwpExAYD9ukQaAWIlwCsRX6xOzxcVkCITbC4/AsuFi8ASyDlJtidvoLBuhJ2TEOcaRVGL6zi4CP0LQhiOOyad2m+m/AzRfeBXcyA1bl/uRnnCkjMhXTaV37s7AhP+0iMccjnM8Rhn6wDE0bgC2FGY5zHfHRyCGw9PkRVUYAdaIhp8gFokHhNrERHnHD8fbPXNjSCL/LhK/PRx2cMht/zCby9stEh+UZhbURT/B0PY702C7tC8xxDBuwLwDPug/H4PQvQNKsI9978bvKWrjAK65ZwVcqDywurN4Sc1fju3f27d57/PATSzGvwPqJgL0tuSkRXS5Hr09//MD7M0+3yy+VnWKHhKx7bu7efX9LRLl3HRpiqOwFPlVhcW1zICAqpUvXC8hOn2kbv3j5seaOG8e/ee29cZwkcy7oYOMxicQus6XdyTVbGXbO/2/DMOwMGvG+pVu2c42qQApvMIXi/dLZQuoalz7BcPfK7bNo2xpx1ts7HrUO+bXfq5D0FJ1JDNwJCF+Da0WNNga5OeNku8FVsCFY4zjdF67KZA4j+YyNMTnq+okLvkIyLddpWrXp+weEDPeccOHLfN3q+nj3jwqHhbF5u9X5n04MDMn6tE9ap5xeNIGG8eLFOx7x8X5c6gUe+NDiVeNg8MG1ec5Q+JIiK0nC2Vkf9unYIUZPTUevc94iKshsT0PRiZp2pB/f16pKSFNIxYsKT1SFgEkA96fiq2Gcrwex5HZEVEY++QuCRnOy7QooKPf38/E/+kJ0VsParFS9Ovxm/tJSW8zb9FDnnwYfeOFCjxi+nzDGzVkO4xcLmNNg4/olHAdRwrYJ/FuWgZ8cUrDvkWgMXpBe6Fv8C5xO18e7p0fjKMAen785ESgBg0wDPYiD0ONDiDJDiB2wI8sbGtPtx/EJTRIm16I+Dv7vOtLG+O+Y0qI8OeedR1SsTIak3Cus72Ryz0QPv1ozBzpYl6HIU8EqvgiEYj8n1zSiok4VBCUCVgtu/fiis22f4V4/wm7BM0ffqa1cDB7z9Qq3A1GHShg9jwxF/Q8Ari+7X3xK2bPX903v39g1JTw9GSOga5OX54vDh7jAYSvIGD3pnpbvb5bzFS2Z212dm+u0jJPLWfzshIzcnoP2wYS+n2UsMF+cvmn3PvzPD0oWli0LPZs91ey83t6Z//J7B8vQvzbtBasmQ2kDERZy5JrsxZhSkHNa92wJT46a79XNzd20buvDUmRZLBg6YlWpwsvy6ZMlbfRsE7S3NJ3Bm+dIZ2XapNXlo6IuvuBgQBQ0HF8yfZW/YYM+Izl2W/qJptgvXCMsU3Qp2sRIQMxB4diEQhYjBCNFs0G+RayQd7Zy3Y8fQej3bz5sQ1OzANEikWb3xoT0b1V2cMNVqczmTmNA/q179/RNOHA/FocM9An28MxN0PtYSZ+dly1/vUK/2kTcq4qcJW7o5Nrp6mzbra4eGr8xZvWpS+rn0RrWGD3h+qk9gwSuWYref9+3t66KPjUONm20+cT+6uh/E0JBFsEmBtT+PRIK/J9oHb0a3Q8DQi2k41KwQJ2sCg+JLhXGkDpBYH0iXVbEs7UHMPL0LfXHkpj28tY47JhWPwOTCLcgNO442aTcX1ov1o5FU34rBCYDlcqmwXq41D+lNM9DzIBB0B1YkKay/Wje3//nlhRUMu1jywJCZn/j5pXUwSLw0NwyppR8hBcZFt4ZwKn36ptm3VCSspKQuIjRk1ZtuHnm9AUw3hyJdP9yYgJbWErdp69Y/3d7HMytKv+CkxOrY2Bg/SNl79NhnfnKCLVi/zfP0zjT/0S1hmbD0mY0xAW0FMAGAv9XqJE6mtW6bX1h1Z/OmGyL02cpVRFeE9fjISQvcPfIesErMnBcTm6Gvq/W6L/rT2nUP91q/fmLbCvLdHWGM3KEJdJPAS2ZzzFBIe++xYyYecHK2VKtohiVgfb1Bg713hYauSvOpeuE8BNamXMLXW5bFjNClqWdw88wbZCnBqwvbO9bEAGNMLUisBKQFwHLY5TYYtF6QspvOR9i0Zvq6Xd3AJIewrufn4mSpv2LlPzZYLW4vDRr8XurOnQ8FJx/tEGWaEJldXOg6ft3a55pcyAjSn6QuT8Trs39AM/yIYDx5z1xkV7Fh8M/AT4E++CHIGxv2D0FB5l34Vsx2rFs5OkAK7BV18Irsh+yAPPRuuB53OWehxRmJNqmocJ3pvPRBd/F3vO61GNnhKRUKq+yWcFbQu/i1dhEeiAeOF9fGKIxGjM/HSGqThU7JQLCjk27vRWHdHr/KcPYNi+6hYauy27ZZ536NsCLnBsEu1gLiKdi1IxUJKyR85ag98QOahISvifPxutj2+i9nLXHRNm4a19LFyfKSfsEJiRUxsTEBNxPWwQP3yZ27HnZDyrkIbImywhjTH1JO0G8Jiyxew1eumdSwKNejJxY+eU7/rMi9CLLZ0f1kaqvnvT2z3Gr4n95lB96MC0GSI8uVW8JHHnlpSRWfjCCHaD6ICQawMDzsmydbtNgc8f0GYwcPl/yXr+Yzm22AnDhqzPPfubrmVzWHyCmOxW0pm+sS0SVxjbCufGn91rm40OOFw4e71kzYM8hdSkPpGpaQHWAXHzz66JSl3t7ZDa8594noh6GJCDhZHxr32JMuTs7omZrW+kmhyYb16h7aa7U455QX1vX89Cw7dz006+CBXsv69J5zOfeyf5OdP/ZvZ3zqueEZ5+t1Xr12kosV2oP62BN+ROayao2Q7umCDm5HUbXQ7hCFTQBrQ4DzngbsKL4brc8VwXT6OJIKGlW4hqXPtuIbAmEnbpw56Sj+HWGVLbpPr/8xCgOzHDm2FjfHTNkHcVU+wrY2xRRWZTBFJclww7YG/1onVnfs9PlZg9Xyjy8Hpv94dVuDEGnIPmoc8tjXfTdvG/u2X41fXi2/htW526IBO7cPb1at+q+X7m667UhWru/UFV++qq87mSDEUNg1e5nofk9Ybh75yx8eMiP82LFOuT/+9PhgaHIApPgVEu8BMsdkjEyw2pz7Llv+WkBBXtUcGOxTER15CkazE+yyO4R4u0XzDf/o2OmL4QBSzWF43cH6yqJ7u3Zf+7RsvjE18XD/mYm7++nrY8mjh06M1rzFjBuEFRuzRV9073lv3LlGDRNSzLEx6x2L7kLuGTPumW3OmqVBRcLqvhlOjb3RWwBDiiyuVQ7s6+N68HDPD6yXqu2Ce+Hyzp2WWpo23ZaZeqpF1KYfJkwBpDskvoYQ74eFfD2xdeh3j+bm+NU6drRzx9wcv+PdeyxcISQa/JGwHFlmRb/asGFCROMmO8761jwz3NP1UkTayTbZP3wfObBs7HpHqz6+Jqsrqma6ItJvBQ56V8Gq+FFYWrQYDcQFfFe9FmbVvRs9fXfBIO1IPdAVz2bsd8y2pJBIDgASGwDFznA8+budGVbZtoai+ukICdqGLglemHR5lGNbQ6+AH7G1KXhLWElkURli3LBxNGDG022aN93++YULQXX3H+jlAqld3ThqGj+micXuMn3r1pHhmsSL129ryMoI/OlocufH/f1PtE/c28+enR2wwTErM5tOlG041W8lKxKWPkP4/KtXjhXme7/Vs8e8lMBaKTPiFnzYuEXzjS96e2c6JSQMXlxid54cMW58TwF0P5LU+Y38fN+3alQ/PWD3z0O8Ll3yLwHkRkhtImKNyeN2Or+XnNxh4NbtIz6E2TTbATtyrl+zpluX1vJP6bF3f5/8rKzaHwJ4PWKcqYvV7mIsf0vomMHo2yrGzW3RrOVPq2vWPFUvcU+/LZcv1zgA2F2NpgkZkPCrSFhXCxsFrfwaFgS+/WbFU9t9fXMW1aqV0mnPnv7FuZf8P4NmnwK7lg1gSpPG21/0vytVS0wYsCovv4ousWl/e3TqOlfnQr9/T1jmbj4+57/o3XvurmrVzq4TAs0K8z3+9cmS9weUjR24O8ipf1Ey3hB98c/Wb8PmVYRf47vj3aIByBReqCcz8QGWo4vHfqwOB+pdBLoc+W0NS9P3kJwEmp0GDL/zM+qKZlhNUl0xDBHoLY7gGWxyoHJsHK3ZDWktM5F6tAPGph93bBzdX9+GpDrgontlMEUlyVDhT3OMu9CjbFuD3YrFcd8io2xbgxS4ZPPCS66XUdMm8Kp+YWtAYtnfhSXY6e6CVwBkWzS8nVeEPF9njJRAe2nHTCcN1rJjy7YtGPfgOdjRpGwh3VCAN+xAvHtVLC7KwTAB9LNreFcWI83gjCmQKDKHY7q+hUHoi+FAiWbHvJj1ODj0frhWdUY/oWHwof3ddu7Y/WgRYiL17QuO17jD8DUUOp7i5doseMcm4OPqjBekQKarD1615iDw+nyjdyKobNF9ftwHXs2abwtt1/6LIgAXS5wwdWEb5PxRPfWnhBIYoUkkWD2w1akQr0vglNULc0QWnA0umKxvAbHZkGjQMBACs5IvY0+wFx4WwMOOnfwCLxok3H+Pn+OJZRQ0Y3+8KQSaSInT1mJMm98ZlyN+xjAhMGTKSgyvm1G6gK7PlNwtcCx2JwUASbVLZzT1Mkv/vb0J0DkZcLICB+qV3vrp52p/9IXLvX/RG1gZhgrXsMoOsxqA1SGAXQD37wfyXeHYk1UrC9zWcAus/9sPvelvCSP2IkxY8bgE6mgCBrtEkQC2W70xb35TXB4fjwYVCUuXUMTPaF72yP4KwHMQiDGHIrH8eRUJS7/gTAl4WkrcBw1Hs4sRVc0Zz0sgTMDxvwc5YQU+mn/lgcCYRNR0scMkJVoIAU8pHdswzkknxMXOjelaL+jAjt695oyChmNlWyTGxqOBvq0BQEMhHA/J9tuK8aG+SH9NvrjobNhFLKT2gDEywqeowHtyZlZAd0/P3G3Vqp3bLwUM5hDHnq5bfkXsRmNoeKpsW4MmcKJEYs7lEqSXfd8rg/4CiYNCQ3cAMw0S+X8oLH0XSDxGCmCovnZmDkOMPtbQHXDXx2510iFs+OYBgVlAciDQZx9QMxfY3BxI8y/d1uBiBe45BYQdvzVBXQ+jImHpQvomDPDPBe47WHpGjkeppC746Kv8QFBG6XvcOHrL7fVfe0Ll+vHz/xNmUzz6QaBuTCiib+kjjDHOAJ6FxLOO3ytKnIKUE/WNncZ4MQ0CXuZQTL2lMSvBwX/GT3Mqwde8IQKfElbGqtxapv8JYRnjMdkG7JgXhu23hqf06Ig9GCLseMSuYU5cCLaOi0cngwaTtGFNbDg+/0/G/CvPobD+Svr87Nsh8D8hrNsBVO5W6mn9tlQTcANQADtWx6zD0vK/BLjdz/mzzqew/izS/Jw7TYDCutNEFRiPwlKgSIxYIQEKi41BAiSgDAEKS5lSMSgJkACFxR4gARJQhgCFpUypGJQESIDCYg+QAAkoQ4DCUqZUDEoCJEBhsQdIgASUIUBhKVMqBiUBEqCw2AMkQALKEKCwlCkVg5IACVBY7AESIAFlCFBYypSKQUmABCgs9gAJkIAyBCgsZUrFoCRAAhQWe4AESEAZAhSWMqViUBIgAQqLPUACJKAMAQpLmVIxKAmQAIXFHiABElCGAIWlTKkYlARIgMJiD5AACShDgMJSplQMSgIkQGGxB0iABJQhQGEpUyoGJQESoLDYAyRAAsoQoLCUKRWDkgAJUFjsARIgAWUIUFjKlIpBSYAEKCz2AAmQgDIEKCxlSsWgJEACFBZ7gARIQBkCFJYypWJQEiABCos9QAIkoAwBCkuZUjEoCZAAhcUeIAESUIYAhaVMqRiUBEiAwmIPkAAJKEOAwlKmVAxKAiRAYbEHSIAElCFAYSlTKgYlARKgsNgDJEACyhCgsJQpFYOSAAlQWOwBEiABZQhQWMqUikFJgAQoLPYACZCAMgQoLGVKxaAkQAIUFnuABEhAGQIUljKlYlASIAEKiz1AAiSgDAEKS5lSMSgJkACFxR4gARJQhgCFpUypGJQESIDCYg+QAAkoQ4DCUqZUDEoCJEBhsQdIgASUIUBhKVMqBiUBEqCw2AMkQALKEKCwlCkVg5IACVBY7AESIAFlCFBYypSKQUmABCgs9gAJkIAyBCgsZUrFoCRAAhQWe4AESEAZAhSWMqViUBIgAQqLPUACJKAMAQpLmVIxKAmQAIXFHiABElCGAIWlTKkYlARIgMJiD5AACShDgMJSplQMSgIkQGGxB0iABJQhQGEpUyoGJQESoLDYAyRAAsoQoLCUKRWDkgAJUFjsARIgAWUIUFjKlIpBSYAEKCz2AAmQgDIEKCxlSsWgJEACFBZ7gARIQBkCFJYypWJQEiABCos9QAIkoAwBCkuZUjEoCZAAhcUeIAESUIYAhaVMqRiUBEiAwmIPkAAJKEOAwlKmVAxKAiRAYbEHSIAElCFAYSlTKgYlARKgsNgDJEACyhCgsJQpFYOSAAlQWOwBEiABZQhQWMqUikFJgAQoLPYACZCAMgQoLGVKxaAkQAIUFnuABEhAGQIUljKlYlASIAEKiz1AAiSgDAEKS5lSMSgJkACFxR4gARJQhgCFpUypGJQESIDCYg+QAAkoQ4DCUqZUDEoCJEBhsQdIgASUIUBhKVMqBiUBEqCw2AMkQALKEKCwlCkVg5IACVBY7AESIAFlCFBYypSKQUmABCgs9gAJkIAyBCgsZUrFoCRAAhQWe4AESEAZAhSWMqViUBIgAQqLPUACJKAMAQpLmVIxKAmQAIXFHiABElCGAIWlTKkYlARIgMJiD5AACShDgMJSplQMSgIkQGGxB0iABJQhQGEpUyoGJQESoLDYAyRAAsoQoLCUKRWDkgAJUFjsARIgAWUIUFjKlIpBSYAEKCz2AAmQgDIEKCxlSsWgJEACFBZ7gARIQBkCFJYypWJQEiABCos9QAIkoAyB/wPBqWIev15XIgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==") )
```

Since this is the resulting PNG image, there is no way to reverse engineer it to determine the values used in the source code which generated it.

**References**

- [Standards-based curation of a decade-old digital repository dataset of molecular information](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4550659/)
- [The Web Never Forgets: Persistent Tracking Mechanisms in the Wild (pdf)](https://www.ftc.gov/system/files/documents/public_comments/2015/10/00064-98109.pdf)
- [Native Cryptography In The Browser, An Exploratory Approach (pdf)](http://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2901&context=theses)
- [Using JSON for Binary Data Transfer - JavaScript JSON Cookbook (2015)](http://apprize.info/javascript/cookbook/8.html)